# Spring(boot)-redis caching- does it need repository creation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I would like to ask a question about the spring cache annotation and repository creation.

I am trying to cache my values in redis using the Spring boot.
(I have a value, if it is not in cache, I need to cache it, if it is in cache, I need to get it from there)

I have seen a couple of tutorials on line, some using the cache annotations and others simulating the cache repository. (maybe they do not exclude each other, this is my question about)

Here are some of the tutorials that I have read:

1. [Cache annotation tips](https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks)
2. [Caching Data using Redis](http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2014/12/18/caching-data-in-spring-using-redis/)
3. [Intro to Redis with Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/intro-to-redis-with-spring-boot)
4. [Spring Boot Redis cache](https://www.journaldev.com/18141/spring-boot-redis-cache)

Some of the above use the @Cacheable, @CachePut and @CacheEvict annotations:

```
    @CachePut(value = 'user', key = "#id")
    @CacheEvict(value = 'user', key = "#id")
```

and prefix the supposed-to-be-stored class with the following annotation:

```
@RedisHash("balance")
```

They also extend the JPA or CrudRepository. The 3rd one one, however, creates its own repository.

My question is:
If I used the above annotations (@Cacheable, @CachePut and @CacheEvict) should I create a repository for the class objects I am interested in storing by extending the CrudRepository? 
Or does spring create it automatically when using the above annotation and manage it automatically?
An if you extend the CrudRepository yourself, how would you retrieve the items by key from Redis?

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer is no because the cache is transparent to the caller and there is no need to manage it by repository manually.

Comment: Hi Guisong, thanks for the answer, I think the same but a lot of people keep creating it, so maybe it is needed

Answer (score 1):

No this is not needed. Notice that the third link does not mention caching up front. There are two projects , spring cache with a redis cache provider and spring data redis. The third link is talking about the larger and more general use case. Spring data redis is meant to support redis as a full fledged persistence layer. However you are certainly free to only use redis as a caching layer. In this case you do not need to do anything nor should you besides using the normal annotations